# Visual Studio - *.exe has triggered a breakpoint - despite no "break with thrown" enabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2017

I have a large MFC project I'm debugging in visual studio 2017. I recently upgraded the code to 64 bit from 32 bit. Now, when I press a certain hotkey, I get an exception raised before the program enters the code that I wrote to handle the hotkey.

[image]

As I understand it, this means that somewhere some sort of exception was thrown *and caught* (if it wasn't caught I should have gotten a "unhandled exception" error) and visual studio thinks I might like to know that. For some reason it doesn't tell me what type of exception was thrown, and as far as I can tell I have no way of finding that out. The VS debugger breaks in some external assembly code:

[image]
[image]

Importantly, under exception settings I have all "break when thrown" options disabled:
[image]

and if I uncheck the "Break when this exception type is thrown" box in the "Exception Thrown" window, nothing happens, and the next time I hit the hot key the exception is thrown again and the box has a check again. I'm a bit lost in where to go from here. Unfortunately the project is quite large and I can't simplify it to make a minimal reproducible example. If anyone has any ideas or advice, I would be forever grateful. How can I get rid of this visual studio alert?

Comment: It looks like you are hitting random debug break (`int 3`) instruction most likely caused by jump to invalid location somewhere in your code.

Comment: The only way to get rid of the alert is to fix your bug that causes it. It could be that your old code is assuming that pointers are 32 bits wide, and it could also be pretty much anything else.

Comment: It could be numerous things, and without isolating the code for it, it's going to be really hard to tell. It could be a latent debugging break-point previously set & removed that is showing back up, could be a pointer-bug, could be an uninitialized variable causing UB, it could be trying to free memory that was already freed or allocated from another heap. Too many things it could be.

Comment: `int 3` is literally a *debug break*, it means to enter the debugger when one is available. It cannot be disabled in Visual Studio, [it seems](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/612258/cant-disable-break-on-debugbreak-exception.html).